# c++ push reference node to stl list

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, reference, stl

while using dictionary and stl list structure, values in dictionary and nodes in list need to be same objects (by reference and not copies).
how does one push_back into list nodes by reference?
so when I need to set fields in object both structors will be updated

Comment: What did you try so far? Hint - pointers.

Comment: If you want to store references in a container you can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Would you mind to provide an answer superior to mine (or edit appropriately). I didn't even consider `std::ref` so far.

Comment: What are _"structors"_, and why _both_? Did you mean multiple references to the same instance?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Feel free to integrate it into your post. I'm on the road  :)

Answer (score 0):

> how does one push_back into list nodes by reference? so when I need to set fields in object both structors will be updated

You cannot, unless your list is templated to contain pointers (or even better [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)).

None of the standard library containers are able to contain references directly.